# Average movement of promise dates by order number

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to understand the average movement in the promise dates from the current promise date (currentprmdate) with respect to the promise dates 7 days ago (prmdate7) , 14 days ago(prmdate14) and then 28 days (prmdate28) ago in terms of days at a plant, segment ,model level...Also I want to find the distinct number of ordernumber at this level of aggregation..

The calculation is average difference in days (currentprmdate -prmdate7)

average difference in days (currentprmdate -prmdate14)

average difference in days (currentprmdate-prmdate28)

over segment ,plant and model

**Input table**

| ordernumber | segment | plant | model | currentprmdate | prmdate7 | prmdate14 | prmdate28 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V89121 | vinots | Chikoo | HJ781 | 5/6/2021 | 5/5/2021 | 5/1/2021 | 5/7/2021 |
| LM12781 | vinots | Chikoo | HJ781 | 5/17/2021 | 5/11/2021 | 5/15/2021 | 5/10/2021 |
| JK9812 | vinots | Chikoo | HJ781 | 5/3/2021 | 4/28/2021 | 4/25/2021 | 4/20/2021 |
| LP18921 | Vimar | Jolie | MK241 | 4/3/2021 | 3/27/2021 | 3/21/2021 | 3/20/2021 |
| BN1231 | Vimar | Jolie | MK241 | 6/10/2021 | 6/5/2021 | 6/3/2021 | 6/1/2021 |
| LO1231 | Vimar | Jolie | MK241 | 7/15/2022 | 7/11/2022 | 7/13/2022 | 7/7/2022 |

**Output table**

| segment | plant | model | Average 7 day | Average 14 day | Average 28 day | distinct number of orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vinots | Chikoo | HJ781 | 4 | 5 | 6.3 | 3 |
| Vimar | Jolie | MK241 | 5.3 | 7.3 | 10.3 | 3 |

Please find the DDL below:

```
Input table

create table input
(ordernumber varchar(40),
segment varchar(20),
plant varchar(10),
model varchar(15),
currentprmdate date,
prmdate7 date,
prmdate14 date,
prmdate28 date)

insert into input values
('V89121','vinots','Chikoo','HJ781','5/6/2021','5/5/2021','5/1/2021','5/7/2021'),
('LM12781','vinots ','Chikoo','HJ781','5/17/2021','5/11/2021','5/15/2021','5/10/2021'),
('JK9812','vinots','Chikoo','HJ781','5/3/2021','4/28/2021','4/25/2021','4/20/2021'),
('LP18921','Vimar','Jolie','MK241','4/3/2021','3/27/2021','3/21/2021','3/20/2021'),
('BN1231','Vimar','Jolie','MK241','6/10/2021','6/5/2021','6/3/2021','6/1/2021'),
('LO1231','Vimar','Jolie','MK241','7/15/2022','7/11/2022','7/13/2022','7/7/2022')

Output table

create table output
(segment varchar(20),
plant varchar(20),
model varchar(40),
avg7day float,
avg14day float,
avg28day float,
distinctorders int)

insert into output values

('vinots','Chikoo','HJ781','4','5','6.3','3'),
('Vimar','Jolie','MK241','5.3','7.3','10.3','3')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ordernumber ORDER BY orderdate) AS Rn
 FROM #input i WHERE i.code1 IN ('SLD','SPP','SOB') OR i.code2 IN ('SLD','SPP','SOB'))
    
 SELECT * FROM cte WHERE Rn = 1
```